# Querying/getting EID ( Edge id's of network ) in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, c#, network-analyst

I did a server-side(c#) network analysis and the output is the EID's(NetEid's) which needs a INETelements to query for features and Object Id's.
It takes long time especially when you found many features.
Is there anyway to send the Eid's to Java-script( since I have to mark them and ...) and query through the Eid's on client side or any quicker way to do the query in server-side( maybe just for one layer? )   ?

My code :

```
 INetElements INET2   = ipNetwork as INetElements;

     ipTraceFlowSolver.FindFlowElements(oFlowMethod, oFlowElements, out m_ipEnumNetEID_Junctions, out m_ipEnumNetEID_Edges);
           _ResultEdges = m_ipEnumNetEID_Edges;
       for (int i = 0; i < Ipcount; i++)
                    {
                         var Eid= m_ipEnumNetEID_Edges.Next() ;

                         INET2.QueryIDs(Eid,esriElementType.esriETEdge,out UserClassIDs,out UserID,out userSubId);
    .         
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you cant get the values from eid's client side 
you can do it server side and send the ObjectId's to your CallBack web service method.